Vanishing (self-adjoint) unbounded linear operator on a closed subspace
Let $L: \mathcal{D}(L) \to H$ be a densely defined, closed and positive self-adjoint (linear) unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $H$. $\mathcal{D}(L) \subset H$ is the maximal domain of $L.$
Let $H^{\prime}$ be a closed subspace in $H$, hence $H^{\prime}$ is also a Hilbert space and we can decompose $H = H^{\prime} \oplus {H^{\prime}}^{\perp}.$
Now let us assume that $Lu = 0$ for every $u \in {H^{\prime}}^{\perp} \cap \mathcal{D}(L),$ so $ \tilde{L} := L \big|_{{H^{\prime}}^{\perp} \cap \mathcal{D}(L)} $ is bounded on ${H^{\prime}}^{\perp} \cap \mathcal{D}(L).$ Can we (boundedly) extend $\tilde{L}$ to ${H^{\prime}}^{\perp} $ being $\tilde{L}= 0$ or even conclude that ${H^{\prime}}^{\perp} \subset \mathcal{D}(L)$ with $L = 0$ on ${H^{\prime}}^{\perp}$?

Under the conditions you gave, the zero operator on $H’^\perp$ is certainly an extension of $\tilde{L}$, so the answer to the first question is certainly yes. The second no. In fact, you can easily have $H’^\perp \cap \mathcal{D}(L) = \{0\}$, then you trivially have $Lu = 0$ for all $u \in H’^\perp \cap \mathcal{D}(L)$.

Indeed, if $D(L) \ne H$ then choose any $h \in H \setminus D(L)$, and let $H' = {h}^\perp$.  Then $H'^\perp$ is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $h$ and its intersection with $D(L)$ is trivial.

If I would additionally have $\mathrm{ran}(L) \subset H^{\prime},$ which is equivalent to $ {H^{\prime}}^{\perp} \subset \mathrm{ran}(L)^{\perp} = \ker(L), $ since $L$ is self-adjoint. Then it would work?

@kumquat Then it would, yes, but then you’re already assuming $H’^\perp \subset \text{ker}(L) \subset \mathcal{D}(A)$, so the second question just trivially has a positive answer because you’re assuming that’s the case.
